# Serve content from external server via apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, reverse-proxy

I am running my web app at `abc.com` with apache as the web server.

I have some static pages hosted on SquareSpace... eg. `abc.squarespace.com/landing`

I want to configure apache to serve content from `abc.squarespace.com` when it get's a request for `abc.com/landing`

I've done this in nginx by using proxy_pass with the backend as `abc.squarespace.com` for location `/landing`. But I'm not sure how to do this in Apache. No luck doing research on the web as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did Elvis's answer solve your issue or not?

Answer (score 2):

Message body cannot contain URLs with `abc.com`, so I will be using `example.com` and `example.squarespace.com`.

I believe you are looking for frame forwarding. In order to implement it, use the following steps:

1. On `example.squarespace.com` allow frame forwarding from `example.com` by setting the appropriate HTTP headers via web server configuration:

`X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/`

For detailed explanation refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

2. Verify that [Apache mod_proxy_http](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html) is enabled at `example.com`:

`# apachectl -M | grep proxy_http
proxy_http_module (shared)`

3. Set the following rewrite rules in Apache configuration or `.htaccess` file to serve content from `http://example.squarespace.com/landing`

`<IfModule proxy_http_module>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^landing(.*) http://example.squarespace.com/landing [P]
</IfModule>`

The syntax here is the same as for [Apache mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).

Comment: Use `RewriteRule ^landing(.*) http://example.squarespace.com/landing$1 [P]` with $1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether ask was for a redirection to abc.squarespace.com or proxy the call internally, here are the solutions for both

**Redirection :** browser will hit abc.com/landing and get a 301 redirect which changes url changes to abc.squarespace.com/landing

Add rule to httd.conf or included vhost file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/landing/(.+)"  "http://abc.squarespace.com/landing/$1"  [R,L]
```

**Proxy :** the abc.squarespace.com under abc.com > browser will not no that the page is served from any downstream domain.

*Option 1:* Use a rewrite rule with P(proxy) switch

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/landing/(.+)"  "http://abc.squarespace.com/landing/$1"  [P]
```

*Option 2:* Use a proxypass

```
ProxyPass "/landing" "http://abc.squarespace.com/landing"
ProxyPassReverse "/landing" "http://abc.squarespace.com/landing"
```

Additionally, timeout can be specified if needed and also a ProxyRemote can be configured if routing over any internet proxy is needed

**Good References**

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html
  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html
  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Kinda lame that Squarespace doesn't have this feature